# How do I get the user to input a number in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a quiz using Python 3. The quiz randomly generates two separate numbers and operator. But when I try to get the user to input their answer, this shows up in the shell:

```
<class 'int'>
```

I'm not sure what I need to do. Even if I type in the correct answer, it always returns as incorrect.

```
import random

import operator

operation=[

    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]
num_of_q=10
score=0

name=input("What is your name? ")
class_name=input("Which class are you in? ")
print(name,", welcome to this maths test!")


for _ in range(num_of_q):

    num1=random.randint(0,10)

    num2=random.randint(1,10)

    op,symbol=random.choice(operation)

    print("What is",num1,symbol,num2,"?")

    if input(int)==(num1,op,num2):

          print("Correct")
          score += 1
    else:
          print("Incorrect")

if num_of_q==10:

        print(name,"you got",score,"/",num_of_q)
```

Comment: Do you want `if int(input('Enter the number: '))==(num1,op,num2):`？

Comment: @KevinGuan that should be an answer, that is probably what OP is looking for

Comment: @PreetKukreti Thanks, let me post an answer ;)

Comment: I tried this and it works, but the answers still come up with incorrect.

Comment: Try @MichaelLaszlo 's answer :)

Comment: @PreetKukreti I think I don't need do that, Michael has been post a correct answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
if input(int)==(num1,op,num2):
```

You must convert the input to `int` and apply `op` to `num1` and `num2`:

```
if int(input()) == op(num1, num2):
```

Comment: Furthermore, `input(x)` uses `x` as the message to print, where `x` is implicitly converted to a `str`. `int` by itself is the name of a `type`. A `type`'s str is usually its `repr` and for int, that returns the string `"<class 'int'>"`. This indicates why you were getting that message.

Comment: @CyberSkull311 Please remember accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it working. The reason for the error was you were telling the `input` command to display an `int` as a prompt, rather than converting the returned value into an `int`.

Secondly your method for calculating the answer needed fixing as follows:

```
import random
import operator

operation=[
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

num_of_q = 10
score = 0

name=input("What is your name? ")
class_name=input("Which class are you in? ")
print(name,", welcome to this maths test!")

for _ in range(num_of_q):
    num1=random.randint(0,10)
    num2=random.randint(1,10)
    op, symbol=random.choice(operation)
    print("What is",num1,symbol,num2,"?")

    if int(input()) == op(num1, num2):
          print("Correct")
          score += 1
    else:
          print("Incorrect")

print(name,"you got",score,"/",num_of_q)
```